# Whats the best way to show a marquee progress bar when executing a single line background worker?

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have an execute statement that runs a dbcc checkdb of a huge database. For this I'm running a background worker. Here is what I want.

1.I'd want the main UI thread to wait until the background worker has completed.
2.Close the form once the background worker has completed.

But I can't seem to animate the marquee progress bar. Here is what I tried:

1. Using autoresetevent class, I put the UI thread to wait until the background worker has completed. In this case, the progress bar does not animate.
2. Close the form when in the background worker's runworkercompleted method. - But I can't access the form in this method since it was created by main thread.

Can anyone explain me what is the solution? Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: `I'd want the main UI thread to wait until the background worker has completed` that defeats the purpose of even using a BackgroundWorker.  Just use ReportProgress to update the UI

Comment: I have only one line of execution that takes a long time to complete. In this case I cant use report progress.

Comment: It doesnt sound like there is any point to using a progress bar: the progress is either 0 or 100,

Comment: Seems like you have no way of knowing the progress of the task. I would suggest a rotating circle or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a ProgressBar set to Marquee style and a BackgroundWorker component on your form, then this demo should point you in the right direction:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Enabled = False
    ProgressBar1.Show()
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    ProgressBar1.Hide()
    Me.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ProgressBar1.Hide()
End Sub
```